# Haskell String formattation as in C

Tags: string, haskell, numbers

Is it possible to manipulate strings to output just as it is possible in C, I mean:

> printf("%.2f", number);

is it possible to do the same formating in Haskell?

Comment: Yes, you can work with the `Text.Printf` module (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**`Text.Printf`** module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html), which is part of the `base` package, so it is (normally) already installed. This module is documented as:

> A **C printf(3)-like formatter**. This version has been extended by Bart Massey as per the recommendations of John Meacham and Simon Marlow.

We can make use of the [**`printf`** function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#v:printf), for example:

```
Prelude> import Text.Printf
Prelude Text.Printf> number = 3.1415926
Prelude Text.Printf> printf "%.2f\n" number
3.14
```